# How to get current user SID in Mac OS X

Tags: macos, terminal, active-directory

For my application purpose, I want to get the user information from Active Directory. Especially I want to get current user SID and user account domain SID. Can anyone tell me some way to get this user information?

PS: Any approach is highly preferable (e.g. by running terminal commands or getting the user information from Objective C code).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the shell you may use the command [dsmemberutil](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/dsmemberutil.1.html) to get at least the user SID:

Example to get the SID of a user by username:

```
% dsmemberutil getsid -U username
```

Comment: how to get the user account domain SID?.

Comment: @santhosh I'm already looking into this...

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the -G parameter to get the SID for an AD Group

`dsmemberutil getsid -G <AD Group>`